How to save a special view of an image
I run some R code that gives me a graph, for example this code.
graph_c_2$map_postcodes_within_max_travel_time + mapview::mapview(graph_c_2_commercieel, legend = FALSE)

I would like to have a special view of the graph, with one the toggles untoggled. So in this image:

loc_postcodes... etc... should be untoggled/
I am now looking for a way to store the special view of the graph with a predetermined name. So pseudo code would be like:
name <- graph_amsterdam
#Create graph
graph_c_2$map_postcodes_within_max_travel_time + mapview::mapview(graph_c_2_commercieel, legend = FALSE)
#Store graph

Any advice on how I can make sure the selected view of the graph is stored?

You can use leaflet::hideGroup() on map slot of mapview object:
library(mapview)

m_1 <- 
  mapview(franconia, zcol = "district", layer.name = "franconia") + 
  mapview(breweries, col.regions = "darkred") 

m_2 <- 
  m_1@map |> 
  leaflet::hideGroup("breweries")
m_2



You can also set layer visibility with hide = TRUE:
mapview(breweries, col.regions = "darkred", hide = TRUE)

